# why $\lambda(S^1) \le\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lambda (S_\epsilon) $?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Note : Im posting this question because user is not active for past $3-4$ months

find the lebesgue measure of the unit circle?

My attempt : I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996272/is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-the-unit-circle-0)

> Here is the outline of the given answer

> For a very nice region, the Lebesgue measure in the two-dimensional space measures the area of the region.

> Consider the region consisting on the points $S_\epsilon$ between the circle of radius $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$. The area of this region is

> $$\begin{align*}
> S_\epsilon&=\pi\cdot (1+\epsilon)^2 - \pi\cdot (1-\epsilon)^2\\
> &=\pi\cdot [(1+\epsilon)+(1-\epsilon]\cdot [(1+\epsilon)-(1-\epsilon)]\\
> &=4\pi\cdot \epsilon 
> \end{align*}$$
> Since the circle of radius $1$ (which is usually denoted by $S^1$) is contained in each $S_\epsilon$, we know that

> $$0\leq \lambda(S^1)\leq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lambda (S_\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}4\pi\cdot \epsilon=0.$$
> Thus, $\lambda(S^1)=0$.

**My confusion** : why   $\lambda(S^1) \le\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lambda (S_\epsilon) $?

**My thinking** :  Here  $\epsilon < 1$.Generally we  take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ in most of the book

Now we have  circle  with radius $1$ and circle with radius $1/2$ .

obviously circle  with radius $1$  will be bigger than the circle  with radius $1/2$

$\implies$  circle with radius $1$ will have more measure than circle with radius $1/2$

So $$\lambda(S^1) \ge \lambda (S_\epsilon) $$

Comment: if I read correctly $S_\epsilon$ is not a circle

Comment: @CalvinKhor You have read correctly, indeed this is the issue. Jasmine , draw $S_{\epsilon}$ for yourself, draw $S_1$ and see the inequality now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks u .. ya  i misread actually  i was thinking that  $S_e $is the circle  with radius $1/2$ and $S_e$ is lie  between two circle  of radius $1-e$ and $1+e$

Comment: @jasmine It happens to all of us, I'm sure you'd have understood the proof now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S_\varepsilon = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 - \varepsilon \leq ||x|| \leq 1 +\varepsilon \}$ so if $x \in S^1$ then $||x||=1$, therefore $x \in S_\varepsilon$. Now, remember that given a sequence $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $c$ a real number, if  $c \leq x_n$ then $c \leq \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$.